# Java Applet Application Error

Tags: java, applet

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to view an applet using my browser. Has anybody gone through this problem before? [image]

This is the HTML file saved as index.html. I've created it using eclipse within the bin folder in which starApplet.class file exists.

```
<html>
<applet code="starApplet.class" width="500" height="500">
</applet>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your file name is right or wrong, but assuming it's right, you have to remove the .class extension:

```
<html>
    <applet code="starApplet" width="500" height="500">
    </applet>
</html>
```

Comment: *"you have to remove the .class extension:"*  While it is good advice to remove the extension, it is not mandatory.  Every JRE I've ever encountered will tolerate the `.class` extension.  Any chance of an edit **from** *"you have to"* **to** *"it is good advice to"*?